# How To Change The Body Content Of The Mail While Sending The Mail (Outlook Web Addin Using HTML,CSS,JS & Blazor App)

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing the web addin for the outlook using HTML,CSS,JS & Blazor app.

By using this addin, The content of the new compose mail must be changed when it's being sent.
In short, **I want to change the content of the body of the mail while sending it.**
Here is my code which is in the function file.

```
//INITIALIZE OFFICE
Office.initialize = function () { }

//THIS FUNCTION IS USED TO EXECUTE ON SEND EVENT
async function ExecuteOnSend(event) {
    try {
        const mail_item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        mail_item.body.getAsync('html', function (body_get_response) {
            if (body_get_response.status === 'succeeded') {
                mail_item.body.setSelectedDataAsync("Hello world", { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, function (body_set_response) {
                    if (body_set_response.status === "failed") {
                        console.log("FAILED");
                    } else {
                        console.log("SUCCESS");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.error(body_get_response.error);
            }
        });
    } catch (error_message) {
        console.log("Error occurred : " + error_message);
    }
    event.completed();
}

//REGISTRATION OF FUNCTIONS
Office.actions.associate("ExecuteOnSend", ExecuteOnSend);
```

I have used both `setAsync` & `setSelectedDataAsync` methods. But I was failed to do above stuff.
I have also noticed that, Execution of these two methods, Neither went to the `if` case nor to the `else` case.
So **"FAILED"** or **"SUCCESS"** was not printed on the console.

```
if (body_set_response.status === "failed") {
    console.log("FAILED");
} else {
    console.log("SUCCESS");
}
```

Note that, **Item type of this mail is 'message'** & **'ExecuteOnSend' function is called while sending the mail** & **I am also able to get the body of the mail**.

How to resolve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev Can you look into this

Comment: Please note that @ tagging someone as above doesn't work if they haven't commented or edited the question. (And here on SO, it's not appropriate to go looking to get a specific person to answer your question. Users follow tags, so proper tagging is all that's required.)

Comment: Yes, I am always tracking key tags and read related posts. But it is a pleasure to see my name, that is some kind of a recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you are calling the `body.getAsync` method asynchronously which means it will be running in parallel with the rest of the code in the function. Looks like the following line of code is executed earlier than your callback is invoked and completed its job:

```
event.completed();
```

I'd suggest calling the `completed` method only when the result is retrieved from the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function. So the code may look in the following way:

```
//THIS FUNCTION IS USED TO EXECUTE ON SEND EVENT
async function ExecuteOnSend(event) {
    try {
        const mail_item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        mail_item.body.getAsync('html', function (body_get_response) {
            if (body_get_response.status === 'succeeded') {
                mail_item.body.setSelectedDataAsync("Hello world", { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, function (body_set_response) {
                    if (body_set_response.status === "failed") {
                        console.log("FAILED");
                        event.completed();
                    } else {
                        console.log("SUCCESS");
                        event.completed();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.error(body_get_response.error);
                event.completed();
            }
        });
    } catch (error_message) {
        console.log("Error occurred : " + error_message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Appriciated !! Thanks for this. It worked for me. I have replaced my code with the code provided by you. But it was appending the 'Hello world' to the body. So I used 'setAsync' instead of 'setSelectedDataAsync'. It worked for me. Thanks again..!!